# Dataframe containing np.arrays in each cell into Machine learning method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, machine-learning, lstm

I have a pandas dataframe containing np.arrays in each cell (see the photo to understand better). Each array is 1000 samples long. However, when trying to use this as a training data in LSTM, it won't go through. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OduIz.png)

`model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 15)`

`ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`

How do I tackle this? Can't find an answer elsewhere, tried this:
 `x_train=np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)`

but it failed due ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Is there another way to use this sort of numpy arrays as input?

I was trying to train LSTM with my pandas dataframe data containing 1000 sample long np.arrays

Comment: Most machine learning models expect the input to be an array where each element is a single float. Therefore you have to unpack your array before passing to the model. You could use `df.explode()`.

Comment: Look at `np.asarray(x_train)`.  I expect it is a 2d array with object dtype, containing the arrays.  `np.array(np.asarray(x_train).tolist())` might work to produce a higher dimensional numeric array - if the component arrays are all the same shape.

Comment: All arrays are the same shape and are 2d arrays with object dtype. However, this did not work :/ still complains of the same thing. 

Explode also doesnt work: these are biosignals and the timings are crucial

Comment: It does how ever complain about different value error now. 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

I tried changing the dataframe to np.float32 and 'float32' before this advice of yours. Did not help.